# Can we delete home directory for a particular user?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, command-line

What happens when home directory is deleted, will it go back to root as home directory is sub directory of root directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Users without a home directory just have their home directory set to `/`.

Use `usermod -d / New_Home`  to update the user's home directory.